# PCB Design Process

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I'm new to PCB Design so I wanted to clarify a few things about the process.

For context, I have already physically made my project on a breadboard. Now I am trying to lay it out on a PCB.

1. I have made my design using Altium CircuitMaker and the Schematic and PCB files are made of components that I could find from their library. These components aren't exactly the ones I used to build my project on the breadboard. So, my question is when ordering the PCB from a manufacturer, do they only buy whatever components was used in the PCB design files? Or do they just use those components as a reference and allow me to specify that "I want .... from this other manufacturer" since those are what I actually used for the breadboard prototype.

2. Also, what's the process like if I want to put the components in and solder myself? Does the manufacturer just make the holes and routing on the PCB board without putting the components in and send it to us?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Your question is pretty broad, and a lot depends on what you actually order from your PCB house.  The usual way is they just make the PCBs (ie the etching and drilling and printing and cutting out), they do not populate them with components *unless you actually ask and pay for that*.  Regarding components "not exactly" like what you have, it's all in the detail.  A slightly different resistor value or tolerance will make no difference; a physically different part probably won't fit!

Comment: @jonathanjo Since you are saying that they don't usually populate them, I don't need to worry about not having the "exact same" components in the PCB files as my breadboard prototype? Because as long as they are the same size physically, I can just solder in the ones I have right now in my breadboard design onto the PCB when it comes unpopulated?

Comment: @jonathanjo In that sense, when designing a PCB schematic for something that isn't going to be populated, there's no difference between not using components in your design file (instead just positioning through holes and routing) and using components? What I mean is, you can just position through holes wherever you want the actual component to go in, instead of using the component in your design file right? Because either way, it's not populated by the manufacturer.

Comment: @jonathanjo The reason I ask the above question is because I have a HC-05 module in my breadboard now for which I can't find a footprint on the Altium CircuitMaker library. So, I'm wondering if the way to go about this issue is just putting in through holes for my PCB design where I want the module to go in so I can just solder in the HC-05 when the PCB comes.

Comment: If you can't easily find schematic symbols and PCB footprints for parts you want to use, make the symbols and footprints yourself.  Any ECAD/PCB program should have schematic symboll and PCB footprint editors to make these things.  If you do any amount of electronic design, you WILL have to make some of your own symbols.  It is a good idea to have the actual parts you want to use in hand when you do the board layout, so that you can ensure they do fit your board layout (or even to ensure they do exist and are available!).

Comment: Beware that many ICs are available in different packages - be sure to use the right footprint for the version you buy!

Answer (score 1):

1. As long as you have the same footprints, it would be okay to use alternative parts for the sake of simply creating the circuit board. But if you're providing a BOM and expect a manufacturer to fully assembly your board with the appropriate parts, this would not be okay. Either way, you can find either third party websites (like SnapEDA, Mouser, etc.) or you can contact the supplier of said chip to see if they have ECAD files for Altium.
2. Some manufacturers may provide full assembly, as I mentioned before. Some manufacturers can also lay out traces and vias. It really depends on what services the manufacturers. Generally I lay out the traces vias myself. As far as screw mounting holes or vias, that's part of the gerber that provides drilling instructions so the manufacturer can do that.